# SQL Server : DATEDIFF not accurate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to retrieve the month difference of two dates but it seems like I can't find a way to get the accurate months.

Here are the queries I tried so far :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,convert(datetime, '11/05/2015'), convert(datetime, '12/06/2015')) - 1
```

This will result to 0 which is wrong and when I used another date :

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(month,convert(datetime, '12/31/2015'), convert(datetime, '01/01/2016')) - 1
```

This would yield to 0 which is correct.

Leap year must also be considered.

Comment: `Datediff` counts when date boundaries(`month`) crossed. You need to be careful when using `Datediff`.

Comment: What is your expectations?

Comment: I think the second one should also evaluate the difference as one and then deduct one giving zero. They are both the same.

Comment: Both of these expressions yield 0 for me. Are you certain the second one yields 1? Regardless the function works exactly as described and now it's up to you to describe what functionality you want.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i expect to get the accurate months, given all the possible conditions (leap year, etc.)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, you can try it

Comment: I did try it and I got 0 for both

Comment: @Sick yes you are correct, boundaries are being referenced

Comment: You should explain why you believe the first is incorrect.

Comment: why is zero wrong for the first one? whats the right answer? 1? why? There are lots of edge cases to consider

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes there are many things need to consider, I'm just showing what formula i tried using. Im looking for the right way

Comment: For example one way to calc your first requirement is find days different, divide by 30.0 and round up. But this rule doesn't work for months with 31 days, or when the difference crosses a few months.

Comment: yes, if someone can provide a solution to cater all that scenarios and will yield to accurate results, much better. My question is lacking i cant explain it all

Comment: For example try this for your first case. I _assume_ the asnwer you expect is 1. Now try it for every other case (365^2) and see if it gets the answer you want. `select ceiling((DATEDIFF(day,convert(datetime, '11/05/2015'), convert(datetime, '12/06/2015')))/30.0)-1`

Comment: You need to define "accurate results". It's not like the existing function is wrong or inaccurate, it doesn't do what you want, and you need to define what you want.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry for that cant explain at accordingly, `select ceiling((DATEDIFF(day,convert(datetime, '02/01/1992'), convert(datetime, '03/01/1992')))/30.0)-1` i need ur advice for this, is this considered as one month or not?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid dont get mad, im just needing help here. It is not the right attitude in this community

Comment: Sorry. You'll need to explain your requirements to get some help

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi, not clear why you flagged his post, he is correct, you have not explained to us clearly what you are looking for, and why.  We are guessing what it is you want, but you have yet to confirm.

Comment: @Greg nevermind, i want to revert it, but i cant already, i felt sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TSQL is return the correct results as you have written them.  As you have it, it is taking the difference of the months between the two dates specified.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, convert(datetime, '11/05/2015'), convert(datetime, '12/06/2015'))
```

The difference, in months, between November and December is "1".

However, if you are wanting the difference in terms of every 30 days is 1 month, then you would need to rewrite your query:

```
declare @daysPerMonth int = 30
SELECT (DATEDIFF(day, convert(datetime, '11/05/2015'), convert(datetime, '12/06/2015')) / @daysPerMonth)
```

This works if you define the number of days in a month as 30.

Comment: hi @Greg thanks for your answer, given this data, 
02/01/1992 and 03/01/1992, if you count the days it is less than 30 but if we look at it in month basis, this is considered as one month, this year is a leap year

Comment: Yes, can you explain your point?  In terms of number of months difference, it is 1.  In terms of daysPerMonths, and you are using 30 days per month, then it is 0.

Comment: when using MONTH for datediff, it ignores the day.  ie Feb 1, Feb 18, Feb 29... in the MONTH calculation, it is just Feb.  Same for March.  Thus the difference, in terms of months, between Feb and March, regardless what day it is, is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to visualize what `DATEDIFF(month, ...)` is doing. Think of a monthly calendar hanging on the wall. For the purposes of this particular SQL function "number" of months between two dates is the number of pages you have to flip to get from one date to the next. It doesn't matter how many days are in each month or whether it's a leap year.

You aren't the first person to be confused about the behavior of the built-in function. If you need to count months by a different method then you'll need to describe the specifics of what you want to accomplish. It's very likely that a solution will be easy to create once you define the problem that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can use CASE:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, convert(datetime, '11/05/2015'),
convert(datetime, '12/06/2015')) - 
CASE 
WHEN (MONTH('11/05/2015') > MONTH('12/06/2015') 
OR MONTH('11/05/2015') = MONTH('12/06/2015')
AND DAY('11/05/2015') > DAY('12/06/2015')) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END
```

Which returns 1 which is correct and:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, convert(datetime, '12/31/2015'),
convert(datetime, '01/01/2016')) - 
CASE 
WHEN (MONTH('12/31/2015') > MONTH('01/01/2016') 
OR MONTH('12/31/2015') = MONTH('01/01/2016')
AND DAY('12/31/2015') > DAY('01/01/2016')) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END
```

Which returns 0 which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
    @start date = '20220105',
    @end date = '20220406'

select 'Date_Diff_In_3 months' = 
    case 
     when datediff(month, @start, @end) < 3 
        or (datediff(month, @start, @end) = 3 and day(@start) >= day(@end))
        then 'yes' 
        else 'no' 
    end
```